# Spring MVC - how to return 404 on missing parameters

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I want to trigger 404 page whenever I wasn't passed all of the parameters. Lets say I have the following URI:

```
/myapp/op?param1=1&param2=2@param3=3
```

In case on of the parameters wasn;t invoked I want to return 404 page. I tried doing:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
@RequestMapping(value = "op", params = { "!param1" })
public void missingArg() {
}
```

but then I get an exception telling me there is ambiguity between methods that handle missing second and third parameter.

How can I accomplish this, then?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you're using Spring 3.1 you can define an exception class like so:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public final class ResourceNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
   //  class definition
}
```

Now whenever you throw that exception, Spring will return the http status defined in your `@ResponseStatus` annotation.  For example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/op")
public void methodWithRequestParams(@RequestParam(value = "param1", required = false) String param1, 
        @RequestParam(value = "param2", required = false) String param2) {
  if (param1 == null || param2 == null) {
    throw new ResourceNotFoundException();
  }
}
```

will return a `404` whenever `param1` or `param2` is null.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Although this solution seems a bit awkward to me it got the job done.

Comment: How do you get a custom body/payload

Answer (score 7):

You do not have to implement the `missingArg()` function. If there is no matching method for the incoming request, then Spring's [HandlerExceptionResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers) will handle it and return a response with an appropriate status code.

Spring will automatically convert the request parameters into method parameters if you use the [@RequestParam](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestparam) annotation:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/op")
public void methodWithRequestParams(@RequestParam("param1") String param1, 
        @RequestParam("param2") String param2, 
        @RequestParam("param3") String param3) {

    // do something with params
}
```

By convention, the `methodWithRequestParams()` method will not be called if not all params are part of the request (unless the `required` attribute of the `@RequestParam` is set to `false`).

Also note that the parameters does not have to be Strings.

Comment: The problem with this is that the repsonse code is 400 (or something other than 404) - I don't have control over what response code or what page is being returned.

Comment: Well, a `400 - Bad Request` is in my opinion a more accurate response code that the `404`. After all the resource (identified with by the `/op` url) exists, but the request parameters are wrong, i.e. a bad request. If you would like a specific resource and a `404` response if it does not exist, I suggest that you use `@RequestMapping("/op/{id}")` in conjunction with the [@PathVariable](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates)  annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Echoing what matsev said in the comments of another answer, you should not be using `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)` in this case, but rather `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)`.

`@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)` should be used when the request was formed properly, but the resource isn't there.